# Creating a role/user that only displays list of accessible tables

Tags: postgresql, readonly

I'm trying to tighten up some roles/user privileges for my postgresql db. What I'm trying to achieve is a readonly user to ONLY be able to see the list of tables they have access to.

I've created a role:

```
CREATE ROLE readonly;
```

Granting readonly privileges to certain tables:

```
GRANT SELECT on TABLE table_1 to readonly;
GRANT SELECT on TABLE table_2 to readonly;
```

Created the user:

```
CREATE USER readonlyuser with password '<password>';
```

Assigned `readonly` role:

```
GRANT readonly on readonlyuser;
```

But still, when I run `\d` when I'm signed in as that user it still lists ALL tables (including tables that this user does not have access to)

And same goes for running `\du`, which lists ALL users and roles.

Is there anyway to only display the tables this user has access to and also not allowing to view the users/roles list?

Comment: Not really, that information comes from the system catalogs and you don't want to mess with them. See [System catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/19827.1519688861%40sss.pgh.pa.us).

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I imagined it might not be the best approach